# Calculate $1434661\cdot 3785648743-10020304\cdot 54300201$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm working in the following chinese's remainder theorem exercise:

> Calculate 
>   $$1434661\cdot 3785648743-10020304\cdot 54300201$$
>   You are told that the answer is a positive integer less than $90$. Compute
>   the answer ${\mod 10}$ and ${\mod 9}$, then combine to get the answer.

I've planned a system based on the criterion that the answer is less than $90$ with $d = 1434661*3785648743-10020304*54300201$:

$$\begin{cases}d \equiv 9\pmod{10}\\
d \equiv x \pmod{9}\end{cases}$$

But I'm not sure about the system to be correct, any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: *"You are told that the answer is a positive integer less than 90"* – actually, that is not true.

Comment: It is if you compute it mod 90 - noted in the title of the post but not in the actual question.

Comment: As Martin points out the answer is actually $4887018090000019$ which is *not* a positive integer less than 90.  Whoever whatever the answer is, it is a legitimate question to simply ask "what is the positive remainder when you divide the answer by $90$?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you were told what to do so ... do it.

$$1434661\equiv 1 \pmod {10};⋅3785648743\equiv 3\pmod{10};$$
$$ 10020304\equiv 4\pmod{10}; ⋅54300201\equiv 1\pmod {10}.$$

So $$1434661⋅3785648743−10020304⋅54300201 \equiv 1\cdot 3-4\cdot 1\equiv -1\equiv 9 \pmod{10}.$$

And using the sum of digits for multiples of $9$ rule:

$$1434661\equiv1+4+3+4+6+6+1 \equiv  25\equiv 2+5 \equiv 7 \pmod {9};$$
$$3785648743\equiv 3+7+8+5+6+4+8+7+4+3\equiv 55 \equiv 5+5$$
$$ \equiv 10 \equiv 1\pmod{9}; $$
$$10020304\equiv1+0+0+2+0+3+0+4\equiv 10 \equiv 1\pmod{9}; $$
$$54300201\equiv 5+4+3+0+0+2+0+1\equiv 15 \equiv 1+5 \equiv 6\pmod {9}.$$

So $$1434661⋅3785648743−10020304⋅54300201 \equiv 7\cdot 1-1\cdot 6\equiv 1 \pmod{9}.$$

So there is a unique $0\le x < 90$ so that  $x \equiv -1 \pmod {10}$ and $x \equiv 1 \pmod {9}$.

$x = 9,19,29, .....,$ or $ 89$ and $x = 1, 10 ,19,28,....., $ or $82,$

so $x = 19$.

So $1434661⋅3785648743−10020304⋅54300201\equiv 19 \pmod {90}.$

Answer (score 1):

Simple calculations show that $\,\color{#0a0}{d\equiv -1}\pmod{\!10}\, $ and $\,d\equiv\color{#c00} 1\pmod{\!9}\,$ by casting nines, hence

$\,\ 10\mid \color{#0a0}{d\!+\!1}\,\Rightarrow\, d\!+\!1\bmod 90 = 10\left[\dfrac{d+1}{10}\bmod 9\right]$ $ = 10\left[\dfrac{\color{#c00}1+1}{1}\bmod 9\right] = 10[2]\,$ $\Rightarrow\, d = 19$